# NA outcome when running over() between a SpatialPoints and SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, sp, plot

I am having a problem when `over()` doesn't give a value but keep giving me`NA` for every field in the outcome data.frame. The aim is to have the counts of tardigrade occurrences in each biogeoregion.
Here is my data set and its compositions.

```
#extention=europe area
> tardigrade <- <- gbif("Eutardigrada",ext=e, sp=T, removeZeros=T, download=T)

> tardigrade_sp <- as(tardigrade, "SpatialPoints")
```

> `tardigrade_sp`

```
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 2033 
extent      : -8.250667, 32.14889, 34.66667, 66.28333  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

> `biogeo` # can be find at https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/biogeographical-regions-europe-3

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 12 
extent      : 943611, 8500000, 6e+05, 7800000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 4
names       : short_name, pre_2012,    code,                           name 
min values  :     alpine,      ALP,  Alpine, Alpine Bio-geographical Region 
max values  :    steppic,      STE, Steppic,                 outside Europe 


> over (biogeo, tardigrade_sp)
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Just by watching the extents it appears they're not the same CRS, you assigned that projection to tardigrade sp instead of trnaforming from latlong

Comment: Its definitley something wrong with coordinate systems - we don't know what your `e` is so its hard to exactly replicate your tardigrade data. But it does look like the numbers are lat-long but the coordinate system string definitely isnt. Please edit with the full details and code you used...

Comment: I believe that somewhere, in code that we are not privy to, the  tardigrade_sp object is having a  Lambert azimuthal equal-area (laea) projection assigned to it where it is likely in a lat/long wgs84. If this is the projection comming in on import, it is incorrect.  You need to use the correct projection definition and then transform it to a laea projection using `spTransform`.

Comment: Where does the `gbif` function come from? You don't say. I just tried installing `rgbif` and that didn't have it. Maybe its `spocc`? Nope. OK I give up. We shouldn't have to waste our time trying to guess - please specify all the packages you are using!

Comment: Your first line isn't valid R code. You've written `tardigrade <- <- gbif(` with two `<-` in it.

Comment: @Spacedman So sorry. I have been using package `dismo` for `gbif`. The problem is solved now. Thank you so much for your effort and your advice. I would clarify it better next time. And again so sorry for my mistake. Have a happy new year :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important part you missed was setting the projection on the first `tardigrade` object and then converting either `tardigrade` or `biogeo` object to the CRS of the other object using `spTransform`. It is relevant for answers to include the libraries that were used.

It is also recommendable to use library `sf` for the sake of speed and logic when using spatial data. After the `over` function, I included a `sf` version of the code.

```r
library(dismo)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

# extent from original post
e = extent(-8.250667, 32.14889, 34.66667, 66.28333)
tardigrade = gbif("Eutardigrada", ext = e, sp = T, removeZeros = T, download = T)
# you missed this important step; object tardigrade was not having CRS:
proj4string(tardigrade) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# download and unzip at print(getwd())
download.file("https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/biogeographical-regions-europe-3/zipped-shapefile-format-vector-polygon/zipped-shapefile-format-vector-polygon/at_download/file",
              "biogeo.zip")
unzip("biogeo.zip")

biogeo = readOGR("BiogeoRegions2016.shp")
# transform to epsg:4326 (long-lat)
biogeo = spTransform(biogeo, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

over(tardigrade, biogeo)
# PK_UID  short_name pre_2012        code                                name
# 1        4    atlantic      ATL    Atlantic    Atlantic Bio-geographical Region
# 2        6      boreal      BOR      Boreal      Boreal Bio-geographical Region
# 3        6      boreal      BOR      Boreal      Boreal Bio-geographical Region
# 4        6      boreal      BOR      Boreal      Boreal Bio-geographical Region
# 5        7 continental      CON Continental Continental Bio-geographical Region

# SF code ---------------
e = extent(-8.250667, 32.14889, 34.66667, 66.28333)
tardigrade = gbif("Eutardigrada", ext = e, sp = T, removeZeros = T, download = T)
tardigrade = st_as_sf(tardigrade) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) 

# the file is already downloaded
biogeo = read_sf("BiogeoRegions2016.shp")
# transform to epsg:4326 (long-lat)
biogeo = st_transform(biogeo, 4326)


st_join(tardigrade, biogeo) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(PK_UID)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-1)
# PK_UID  short_name pre_2012        code                                name
# 1       4    atlantic      ATL    Atlantic    Atlantic Bio-geographical Region
# 2       6      boreal      BOR      Boreal      Boreal Bio-geographical Region
# 3       6      boreal      BOR      Boreal      Boreal Bio-geographical Region
# 4       6      boreal      BOR      Boreal      Boreal Bio-geographical Region
# 5       7 continental      CON Continental Continental Bio-geographical Region
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask how long did it take you to plot the biogeo polygons? (it takes me awfully long even with sf) Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, as `sp` it took 33 seconds; as `sf` 9 seconds; if you pass the following code after reading biogeo layer `biogeo = st_simplify(biogeo, dTolerance = 1000 )` plotting takes 0.285 seconds (on a ryzen 7@3 GHz, with 16 GB ram)